# R: writing a function that let's switch between data sets

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function that let's me pick which part of the data (predictors) to use for data analysis (lasso & knn).

Basically what I am looking for is using p() to select it either 3 predictors or 14 to do the analysis with.

```
p <- function(x) { # Choose p(3) or p(14) to use X predictors in analysis.
  if ( x == 3 ) {
  df <- FullData[1:4]
  train = df[ 1:750 , ] # training set
  test = df[ 751:1500 , ] # test set
  train.x = cbind( train[2:4] )
  test.x = cbind( test[2:4] )
} 
  else if ( x == 14 ) {
  train = FullData[ 1:750 , ] # training set
  test = FullData[ 751:1500 , ] # test set
  train.x = cbind( train[2:15] )
  test.x = cbind( test[2:15] )
}}
```

I've tried different combinations of 'if else' if, if' or 'if, else', but I can't seem to tackle the issue. I have a lot of variations of the code above, this one seems to produce the least errors.

I either get this error:

`Error: unexpected 'if' in:
 "  test.x = cbind( test[2:4] )
 } if"`

or this one:

`Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`

Comment: Compare your function with this one `p <- function(x) if(x==3){"three"}else if(x==12){"twelfe"}` As you can see, you have no problem with the ifs rather than wrong or missing commas, or other syntax issues.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. If you have multiple questions, simply make multiple posts.

Comment: What @jimbou means is that the `else` should be directly after the closing `}`, and not on a new line. This is a syntax error.